# Reinitialize Jquery DataTable on Select(DropDown) change event

Tags: jquery, datatable

i am using Jquery UI DataTable, which is filled on `select(DropDown)` `change` event.
On `PageLoad` its ok. When i perform `dropdown change` event, `DataTable` is `Reinitialized` by using `fnDestroy()`, but the format of `DataTable` changes. Below is my code..

```
  campusChangeEvent = function () {
        $('#cmbClassCP').on('change', function () {
        $('#ClassRegistredDataTable').dataTable().fnDestroy();
            GetAllClassbyCampus($('#cmbClassCP :selected').val());
        });
    }, 

 GetAllClassbyCampus = function (id) {
        var oTable = $('#ClassRegistredDataTable').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bRetrieve": true,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/forms/Setup/Setup.aspx/GetAllClassBycampus?CampusId=" + id,
            "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                $.ajax({
                    "type": "GET",
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "url": sSource,
                    "data": aoData,
                    "success": function (data) {
                        fnCallback(data.d);
                    }
                });
            },
            "aoColumns": [
                         {
                             "mDataProp": "RowNo",
                             "bSearchable": false,
                             "bSortable": false,
                             "sWidth": "20"
                         },
                        {
                            "mDataProp": "CampusName",
                            "bSearchable": false,
                            "bSortable": false,

                        },
                        {
                            "mDataProp": "ClassName",
                            "bSearchable": true,
                            "bSortable": false

                        },
                        {
                            "mDataProp": "Section",
                            "bSearchable": false,
                            "bSortable": false
                        },
                        {
                            "mDataProp": "Description",
                            "bSearchable": false,
                            "bSortable": false
                        },
                        {
                            "mData": null,
                            "bSearchable": false,
                            "bSortable": false,
                            "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                                return '<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>';

                            }
                        }
            ]
        });
```

My form looks on `Page Load` like..

[image]

After `DropDown` change event, looks like below..

[image]

Any Help....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i have done it by this method..

```
 $('#ClassRegistredDataTable').dataTable().fnDestroy();
```

This will override **css** of **dataTable** in **jquery.dataTables.css**

By Default it looks like

```
table.dataTable {
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}
```

change it to..

```
table.dataTable {
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

It worked for me..

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$('#ClassRegistredDataTable').dataTable().fnDraw();
```

or:

```
//if you don't want the table reorder/resorted
$('#ClassRegistredDataTable').dataTable().fnDraw(false);
```

Comment: `fnDraw()` and `fnDestroy()` have same effect on my page.

Comment: what happens if you get rid of GetAllClassbyCampus($('#cmbClassCP :selected').val()); after the fnDraw?

Comment: I'm thinking that you shouldn't be trying to initialize the datatable again after it's already been initialized.

Comment: ah, i see. you select a campus from that dropdown and you want it to draw a whole new datatable based on the campus, right?

Comment: This might be a better option for you: http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Answer (score 1):

Even you require to clear your table, like this:

```
$('#ClassRegistredDataTable tbody').html('');
$('#ClassRegistredDataTable').dataTable().fnDestroy();
```