# jQuery DataTable - Go to the last page through JS after init

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm looking for a way to go to the last page of the datatable once it has been initialized through `$('#datatable').dataTable()`.

I found this topic [JQuery Datatables. How can I change the current page programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496054/jquery-datatables-how-can-i-change-the-current-page-programmatically) but it's before the initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if understood the question correctly, but if I did the this should do it. Calling `.dataTable()` second time is [not going to reinitialize it](http://plnkr.co/edit/NA5hEI2sDLxsWCnzR0Ju?p=preview). How to reinitialize table you can [read in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670385/reinitialize-jquery-datatable-on-selectdropdown-change-event).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#yourTableId').dataTable();
  oTable.fnPageChange( 'last' );
} );
```

Comment: The fact is I already used `$('#example').dataTable();` somewhere else to initialize the table and I don't have access to the `oTable` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the demo, your example works fine but I wasn't able to do the same in my app. I'll look more into it.

Answer (score -2):

The simple and working example is 
use

```
$(".datatable").datatable({
 "pagingType": "full_numbers"
});
```